# Mold growth in home

Tags: mold, moisture, demolition

My home is a mold catastrophe. My fiancé was sick for a year and we got an air quality test and it tested the highest level. I started ripping the house apart and found that there was mold in three place.

1. Around windows (easy enough, rehang windows correctly
2. On north side of house close to attic vents
3. Wall behind my toilet with galvanized steel vent pipe running up it.
   I tested the roof where it meets vent for leaks with hose yesterday and go nothing.
   In regards to vents, I want to plug them but have never heard of an attic without vents.
   I live in Santa Rosa California

Comment: Having chased leaks a lot, they are A LOT easier to find when it's raining. Wow, that sounds completely obvious *now that I hear myself say it*,  but 99% of the time when I want to work on leaks, it is not raining.

Answer (score 1):

The code requires “cross ventilation” in the attic. Where you live it may not be much, but check with Building Codes and they can tell you how much.

Like @Jim Stewart says, don’t seal any vents off.

Most buildings codes in U.S. require Attic Ventilation shall be “cross ventilation “ and shall be 1/150th the area that is to be vented. (See ICC R806 Vents.)

However, there is one exception: The attic ventilation can be reduced to 1/300th the area to be vented provided one of the following items are met:

1. a Class I or II vapor retarder is installed on the “warm-in-winter” side of the ceiling, or
2. not less than 40% and not more than 50% of the ventilation is located in the upper portion of the attic. The upper portion is defined as: “Upper ventilation shall not be lower than 3’ below the ridge or highest point of the roof. “  (See ICC R806.1.2.)

So, you can see there is clearly a benefit to having ridge vents, gable vents, etc. , but in a proportion that allows COMPLETE CROSS-VENTILATION to the attic.

You are chasing down the problem the right way. We’ll use a garden hose and soak one area at a time until we make it leak or become convinced it’s solid and dry...then move to the next area.

Answer (score 0):

Get a second independent mold test before you do any modifications. Do your bathroom vent fans just empty into the attic or do they go through ducting out the roof or an outside soffit? Do not seal off any soffit vents.

Comment: Bathroom fan is wall mounted and goes right outside. Attic vents are soffit

Answer (score 0):

Some areas in Santa Rosa have issues with standing water due to the high Clay and poor drainage this can increase the moisture in the home. A dehumidifier can reduce the moisture in the house and will be better than changing the vents (they are required).

I installed a French drain in my grandmothers house starting under her house out to the sidewalk. This allowed the water to naturally drain out from the crawl space. Back then this was legal but putting a pipe to the street through the curb was not. Quite a few homes did the same later. As long as a gravity drain through the rock the city inspector said it was fine (a neighbor turned me in because she thought it was illegal) they had gotten in trouble for cutting the curb.

Behind a toilet is a common place for mold I don’t think I would do any further work other than a dehumidifier and re test, since you have fixed the windows.

carpets are a source also and a weak 3% solution of hydrogen peroxide and water used with a steam cleaner will kill any mold in the carpet and the hydrogen peroxide won’t stink.
I purchase concentrated hydrogen peroxide on line 30% or so , purity chemical used to have it I would check with them (if still in business I have been gone for over 45 years).

So verify that your crawl space is dry it may be dry already this year but check when the rains start again that can increase the humidity inside the home and mold likes moist places. Hydrogen peroxide is a good general use cleaner that will kill mold always remember to AAA . Always add acid to water when diluting.

Comment: Why would mold form behind the toilet?

Comment: Behind the toilet in some/ many homes is only painted if painted prior to the toilet being set. the paper when moist makes a great host for mold, almost every bathroom remodel I have done has had some mold behind the tank even if painted because it is never cleaned. Moisture, dust collect painted or not and since it is not cleaned over time mold grows where you can’t see until the toilet is pulled for a replacement wax seal or flooring update many times 15-20 years so it has time to grow.